# Producer - consumer using MySQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, sql, algorithm

My requirement is as follows

- Maintain a pool of records in a table (MySQL DB).
- A job acts as a producer and fills up this pool if the number of entries goes below a certain threshold. The job runs every 15 mins.
- There can be multiple consumers with each consumer picking up just one record each. Two consumers coming in at the same time should get two different records.
- The producer should not block the consumer. So while the producer job is running consumers should be able to pick up any available rows.

The producer / consumer is a part of the application code which is turn is a JBoss application.

In order to ensure that each consumer picks a distinct record (in case of concurrency) we do the following

- We use an integer column as an index.
- A consumer will first update the record with the lowest index value with its own name.
- It will then select and pick up that record and proceed with that.
- This approach ensures that two consumers do not end up with the same record.

One problem we are seeing is that when the producer is filling up the pool, consumers get blocked. Since the producer can take some time to complete, all consumers in that period are blocked as the update by the consumer waits for the insert by the producer to complete.

Is there any way to resolve this scenario? Any other approach to design this is also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a hard requirement that you use a relational database as a queue?  This seems like a bad approach to the problem, especially since the problems been addressed by message queues.  You could use MySQL to persist the state of your queue, but it won't make a good queue itself.

Take a look at ActiveMQ or JBoss Messaging (given that you are using JBoss)

Comment: Unfortunately yes, we are constrained to use a DB for this purpose.

Comment: Maybe you can forward your architect this article: https://blog.engineyard.com/2011/5-subtle-ways-youre-using-mysql-as-a-queue-and-why-itll-bite-you/

Comment: That was a very insightful article. Thanks for sharing. While this is definitely something to avoid in the future, I am stuck having to make the DB work in some way :(

Comment: The very fact that you have an asynchronous problem (use the terms producer/consumer) really screams JMS.  Why must you re-invent solutions? +1 to Isaiah for suggesting JMS and using MySQL to persist.